# vectorize a function with multiple inputs to form a unique function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a function that takes this form:

```
def signal_prototype(t, A, f, p):
    return A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+p)
```

I would like to vectorize this so that I can use the function as follows.

```
signal_A = SOME_VECTORIZE_FUNCTION(signal_prototype, t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=0)
signal_B = SOME_VECTORIZE_FUNCTION(signal_prototype, t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=np.pi/4)
signal_C = SOME_VECTORIZE_FUNCTION(signal_prototype, t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=np.pi/2)
signal_D = SOME_VECTORIZE_FUNCTION(signal_prototype, t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=3*np.pi/4)

t = np.linspace(0,1e-3,100000)
X1 = signal_A(t)
X2 = signal_B(t)
X3 = signal_C(t)
X4 = signal_D(t)
```

Thank you!

I tried using `np.vectorize` and reading the documentation. There does not appear to be any way to send in static arguments to vectorize.

However, vectorize might not be the best tool for this.

I have a complicated set of differential equations that these signals are an input for. So, I need the functions in the form f(t,x).

The new signal functions are created dynamically as conditions in the model change. So, creating a static version of each equation is not a good option.

Comment: You are probably looking for a `functools.partial` on `np.sin`

Comment: @C.Nivs Couldn't you just do `functools.partial` on `signal_prototype`? That or use a `lambda` function.

Comment: @jared yes, typo on my end, `np.sin` isn't it

Comment: Also, OP, `np.vectorize` is used to take a function that cannot be called using numpy arrays (for example, if you used `math.sin` instead of `np.sin`) and enable them to be called using numpy arrays. That is not what you're looking for here.

Comment: In general, I think you're misusing the word "vectorize". That is typically used to describe writing code that operates on an array (or vector) in a single operation and avoiding writing a loop (but when using Python with Numpy, you're just pushing the loop to compiled code).

Comment: More to the point, since `np.sin` is already vectorized, your job is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.sin()` is already vectorized in that it will work on an array

```py
>>> np.sin(np.array([1,2,3]))
array([0.84147098, 0.90929743, 0.14112001])
```

You can directly call your functions instead

```py
def signal_prototype(t, A, f, p):
    return A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t+p)

t = np.linspace(0,1e-3,100000)

X1 = signal_prototype(t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=0)
X2 = signal_prototype(t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=np.pi/4)
X3 = signal_prototype(t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=np.pi/2)
X4 = signal_prototype(t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=3*np.pi/4)
```

If you want to create a single function for each, you could use `lambda` or `functools.partial` as suggested

```py
signal_A = lambda t: signal_prototype(t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=0)
signal_B = lambda t: signal_prototype(t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=np.pi/4)
signal_C = lambda t: signal_prototype(t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=np.pi/2)
signal_D = lambda t: signal_prototype(t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=3*np.pi/4)

X1 = signal_A(t)
X2 = signal_B(t)
X3 = signal_C(t)
X4 = signal_D(t)
```

Or just return the partial function yourself (effectively the same as `lambda`)

```py
def wrapper(func, **kwargs):
    def wrapped(t):
        return func(t, **kwargs)            
    return wrapped

signal_A = wrapper(signal_prototype, A=1, f=10000, p=0)
signal_B = wrapper(signal_prototype, A=1, f=10000, p=np.pi/4)
signal_C = wrapper(signal_prototype, A=1, f=10000, p=np.pi/2)
signal_D = wrapper(signal_prototype, A=1, f=10000, p=3*np.pi/4)
```

You can extend this if you want to pass a default `t` or make it optinonal, though I can't advise doing so and just have it to illustrate how powerful this is as it's never advisable to return things with different types (such as imo a function with a variable number of arguments)

**do not do this**

```py
def wrapper(func, t=None, **kwargs):
    if t is not None:
        def wrapped(t=t):
            return func(t, **kwargs)
    else:
        def wrapped(t):
            return func(t, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

```py
>>> wrapper(signal_prototype, A=1, f=10000, p=0)(t)
array([ 0.00000000e+00,  6.28324773e-04,  1.25664930e-03, ...,
       -1.25664930e-03, -6.28324773e-04, -2.44929360e-15])
>>> wrapper(signal_prototype, t=t, A=1, f=10000, p=0)()
array([ 0.00000000e+00,  6.28324773e-04,  1.25664930e-03, ...,
       -1.25664930e-03, -6.28324773e-04, -2.44929360e-15])
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! I used partial and that works wonders.

Comment: anytime and welcome to SO - if this Answers your Question, please tick up and mark it as the Answer with the check to its left to help the community and gain some reputation!

Answer (score 0):

The answers above really helped me figure out what I needed to do.

```
X1 = partial(signal_prototype, A=1e-3, f=1e3, p=0)
X2 = partial(signal_prototype, A=1e-3, f=1e3, p=np.pi/4)
X3 = partial(signal_prototype, A=1e-3, f=1e3, p=np.pi/2)
X4 = partial(signal_prototype, A=1e-3, f=1e3, p=3*np.pi/4)
```

now I have my functions that can be called like this.

```
X1(t)
X2(t)
etc...
```

Comment: excellent, but there's no need to do this, SO is not a forum and Mark as Answer is sufficient! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267490/thanks-in-a-comment however, you can certainly edit your Question with additional details (take care not to alter it such that it becomes a new Question, just ask another!) or comment on specific Answers about _how_ they helped you, such as with a wider problem you were experiencing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).